# ¿Cómo seleccionar los id dos tablas que están relacionadas a una tercera tabla?

Tags: mysql

Necesito obtener todos los **id** de la tabla **"dish_options"**  que no existen en la tabla **"assignment"**, esto por medio de **un id** de la tabla **"dishes"**.

**Mis tablas están compuesta de la siguiente manera.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi tabla de "assignment" con datos se ve asi:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**He realizado la siguiente consulta en Mysql**

```
SELECT
o.id,
o.name
FROM dishes AS di
LEFT JOIN assignments AS a ON a.dish_id = di.id
LEFT JOIN dish_options AS o ON o.id = a.dish_option_id
where di.id=51 and o.id != a.dish_option_id
```

**Pero con esta consulta no obtengo ningún dato**
Pero, si quito el signo **" ! "** de mi consulta, este me devuelve los **id** que si existen en la tabla **"assignment"** por medio del **id "51"** de la tabla **"dishes"** y no necesito eso.

**Lo que necesito obtener es algo como lo siguiente:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme dado a entender y de antemano muchas gracias por su tiempo al contestar mi pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigo el problema que tienes es que los datos los quieres sacar de la tabla de **assignments** por lo que te arroja resultados de esta.
La consulta que necesitarias hacer para obtener los de una tercera tabla es la siguiente:

```
SELECT op.id, op.name 
  FROM dish_options op
  INNER JOIN assignments a ON a.dish_option_id = op.id
  INNER JOIN dishes d ON d.id = dish_id
WHERE d.id = 1
```